# SQLAlchemy: How to disambiguate Foreign Key relationships?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I have a simple data model of customer and addresses with SQL Alchemy annotations to make the objects persistable in a database.  Unfortunately, when I try to create a customer object with `c = Customer()` I receive an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child
tables on relationship Customer.addresses - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.
Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as
containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

This is pretty clear -- I need to further annotate the line:

```
addresses = relationship("Address", back_populates="customer")
```

with something disambiguate the foreign key relationships.  However, I can't understand what I need to (or *could*) specify in this case.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Update:** Looking further, it seems to me that SQLAlchemy is attempting to infer the *direction* of the `addresses` relationship and is unable to do so because there are PK/FK relationships *in each direction* between these classes.  This cannot be resolved by adding `foreign_keys=` on the `addresses` relationship because the *foreign* key for this relationship is in the other table.

I can get this to work by removing the `addresses` relation entirely from `Customer` and instead doing `customer = relationship("Customer", backref="addresses", foreign_keys=[customer_id])` in the Address class.  I don't really like this solution, however, as I want to "express" `addresses` in the `Customer` class rather than as the side-effect of creating an otherwise unwanted `customer` relationship in the `Address` class.

So, still looking for a way of modifying the `addresses` relationship to make it work.

Here is my entire model:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Customer(Base):

    __tablename__ = "customer"

    id = Column("customer_id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column("name", String, nullable=False)
    bill_address_id = Column("bill_id", Integer, ForeignKey("addresses.address_id"))
    ship_address_id = Column("ship_id", Integer, ForeignKey("addresses.address_id"))

    bill_address = relationship("Address", foreign_keys=[bill_address_id])
    ship_address = relationship("Address", foreign_keys=[ship_address_id])
    addresses = relationship("Address", back_populates="customer")

class Address(Base):

    __tablename__ = "addresses"

    id = Column("address_id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    address = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64328201/why-am-i-getting-ambiguousforeignkeyserror/64880376, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63740297/sqlalchemy-table-defining-relationship-using-two-foreign-keys/63752082

Comment: Also possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65413861/2144390

Comment: Thanks, but so far, all three recommended links are for a slightly different question -- in which there's a many-to-many join between the "major" table and itself, contained in a "minor" table.  In my case my "major" table has three joins to the "minor" table -- two are one-to-one and the other is many-to-one.  I have the two similar one-to-ones working, I can't get the one-to-many working.

Comment: The reason for my suggestion was to show that a `@hybrid_property` could combine the results from other relationships in the same class.